# Why is this code running twice?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-import

I am writing a Neural Net program to play connect four in python, and training it using existing minimax algorithms. I have written some basic code to establish communication between two algorithms. Following lines should result in one game between the two programs :-

`game = ConnectFour()
game.start_new()`

However, the game is played twice. ("IA is the winner" is printed twice.)

I added some debug print lines. There's a lot of code, but I cannot figure out the point where the problem is. So I am posting all of it. I suspect `import` statements, but do not know what is the problem exactly.

ConnectFourAIb.py:

```
from minimax2b import ConnectFour

def get_AI_move(grid):
    i = 0
    while grid[0][i]!=' ':
        i += 1
    return i

game = ConnectFour()
game.start_new()
```

minimax2b.py:

```
import os
import random
import time
from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod

CONNECT_FOUR_GRID_WIDTH = 7
CONNECT_FOUR_GRID_HEIGHT = 6

CONNECT_FOUR_COLORS = ["x","o"]

class ConnectFour(object):
    _GRID_WIDTH = CONNECT_FOUR_GRID_WIDTH
    _GRID_HEIGHT = CONNECT_FOUR_GRID_HEIGHT
    _grid = None
    _round = None
    _finished = False
    _winner = None
    _current_player = None
    _players = [None, None]
    _COLORS = CONNECT_FOUR_COLORS

    def __init__(self):
        print("__init__")
        self._round = 1
        self._finished = False
        self._winner = None
        self._players[0] = _HumanPlayer(self._COLORS[0])
        self._players[1] = _ComputerPlayer(self._COLORS[1])
        for i in xrange(2):
            print('%s play with %s ' % (self._players[i]._type, self._COLORS[i]))

        self._current_player = self._players[random.randint(0, 1)]
        self._grid = []
        for i in xrange(self._GRID_HEIGHT):
            self._grid.append([])
            for j in xrange(self._GRID_WIDTH):
                self._grid[i].append(' ')

    def start(self):
        print("start")
        while not self._finished:
            self._next_move()

    def start_new(self):
        print("start_new")
        self._round = 1
        self._finished = False
        self._winner = None
        self._current_player = self._players[random.randint(0, 1)]
        self._grid = []
        for i in xrange(self._GRID_HEIGHT):
            self._grid.append([])
            for j in xrange(self._GRID_WIDTH):
                self._grid[i].append(' ')

        self.start()

    def _switch_player(self):
        print("_switch_player")
        if self._current_player == self._players[0]:
            self._current_player = self._players[1]
        else:
            self._current_player = self._players[0]

    def _next_move(self):
        print("_next_move")
        column = self._current_player.get_move(self._grid)
        for i in xrange(self._GRID_HEIGHT - 1, -1, -1):
            if self._grid[i][column] == ' ':
                self._grid[i][column] = self._current_player._color
                self._check_status()
                if self._finished:
                    self._print_state()
                    return 1
                self._switch_player()
                self._round += 1
                return 1

        print("This column is full. Please choose an other column")
        return

    def _check_status(self):
        print("_check_status")
        if self._is_full():
            self._finished = True
        elif self._is_connect_four():
            self._finished = True
            self._winner = self._current_player

    def _is_full(self):
        print("_is_full")
        return self._round > self._GRID_WIDTH * self._GRID_HEIGHT

    def _is_connect_four(self):
        print("_is_connect_four")
        for i in xrange(self._GRID_HEIGHT - 1, -1, -1):
            for j in xrange(self._GRID_WIDTH):
                if self._grid[i][j] != ' ':
                    # check for vertical connect four
                    if self._find_vertical_four(i, j):
                        return True

        return False

    def _find_vertical_four(self, row, col):
        print("_find_vertical_four")
        consecutive_count = 0

        if row + 3 < self._GRID_HEIGHT:
            for i in xrange(4):
                if self._grid[row][col] == self._grid[row + i][col]:
                    consecutive_count += 1
                else:
                    break

            if consecutive_count == 4:
                if self._players[0]._color == self._grid[row][col]:
                    self._winner = self._players[0]
                else:
                    self._winner = self._players[1]
                return True

        return False

    def _print_state(self):
        print("_print_state")
        if self._finished:
            print("Game Over!")
            if self._winner != None:
                print(str(self._winner._type) + " is the winner!")
            else:
                print("Game is a draw")


class _Player(object):
    __metaclass__ = ABCMeta

    _type = None
    _color = None

    def __init__(self, color):
        self._color = color

    @abstractmethod
    def get_move(self, grid):
        pass


class _HumanPlayer(_Player):

    def __init__(self, color):
        super(_HumanPlayer, self).__init__(color)
        self._type = "Human"

    def get_move(self, grid):
        from ConnectFourAIb import get_AI_move
        return get_AI_move(grid)



class _ComputerPlayer(_Player):
    _DIFFICULTY = 5

    def __init__(self, color,_DIFFICULTY=5):
        super(_ComputerPlayer, self).__init__(color)
        self._DIFFICULTY = _DIFFICULTY
        self._type = "IA"

    def get_move(self, grid):
        return 4
```

Comment: Honestly, there's *far* too much code here to work out what is going on. Cut it down to the minimum necessary to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (__"why isn't this code working?"__) must include the desired behavior, a _specific problem or error_ and the _shortest code necessary_ to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a __clear problem statement__ are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve].

Comment: @aryamccarthy I reduced the code size as much as I can.

Comment: @DanielRoseman As you said, I cut it down to the minimum necessary

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's still too much code to go all the way through, but at least one thing is suspicious. You start the game with a module-level call to ConnectFour in ConnectFourAIb.py. But your `_HumanPlayer.get_move` method imports ConnectFourAIb again; this will re-trigger the two lines at the end of that file.

To fix this, use the `if __name__ == '__main__'` trick:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    game = ConnectFour()
    game.start_new()
```

This ensures that those lines are only called when the file is run from the command line, not when it is imported.

(As an aside, please drop all those leading underscores. They don't add anything and just make your code harder to read.)

Comment: That did it! Thanks. I specificaly used `from x import y; y()` instead of `import x; x.y()`. Why did that not work?

Comment: While this is absolutely the way to go, another remedy is taking your `import` out of your function, putting it at the module level. There's not a good reason for it to be inside the function.

Comment: Also, as I said, this is existing code of someone else, and he used the `_`s.

Comment: @MeetTaraviya In what particular way did it "not work"?

Comment: Why is it executing other lines of code when I am just importing `y` from `x`.

Comment: It did work, but to import anything from a module Python still needs to parse and execute the whole thing.